# How can I install virtual box guest addition

Tags: virtualbox

I have install an 'Ubuntu server' environment on top of Virtual box which runs under Windows7.

How can I install virtual box guest  addition?
I have added the 'GuestAddition.iso' file under 'Storage'. But when I start the machine, I go to '/media/cdrom', there is nothing under that directory.

how can I fix it? I want my 'Ubuntu server window' (defined by Virtual box) bigger.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, install the virtualbox additions from your distro version's official repositories:

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But after I install and restart my 'Ubuntu server' machine, I still can't resize my 'Ubuntu' window?

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to mount the 'cdrom' inside ubuntu - try typing `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom` then cd to /media/cdrom and try runnning what's in there. Alternately, if you start a file browser (if you have a GUI installed) you might be able to mount it from inside that. I think server editions of ubuntu don't automatically mount anything.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "resize the window" - are you running the server in console (text-only) mode, or with a GUI? If you're using console mode, you might need to either set the resolution in virtualbox (e.g. http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-easily-change-resolution-in.html) and/or set the console resolution via grub e.g. http://www.mikeplate.com/2011/11/08/change-virtual-console-resolution-on-ubuntu/