# How to install Virtual Box Guest Additions on Debian?

Tags: virtualbox, debian

I have a **Debian** 8.1 (headless) virtual machine (guest). How do I install the Virtual Box Guest Additions?

The question [How can I install virtual box guest addition](https://superuser.com/questions/503176/how-can-i-install-virtual-box-guest-addition) is answered for **Ubuntu** by

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
```

but that doesn't work for me:

```
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
```

Comment: The package in repositories if often outdated, consider using the one that is bundled with VirtualBox and can be inserted as a virtual CD.

Comment: The answer to mentioned question says: "Instead, install the virtualbox additions from your distro version's official repositories." So what now? So far I used only apt-get to install Software. How would I install something from a CD?

Answer (score 32):

From my experience Guest Additions that are bundled with VirtualBox work better. Here are steps to install them. All commands have to be executed as root.

0. Install kernel headers, build tools and DKMS:

   ```
    # apt update
    # apt install build-essential dkms
   ```

   DKMS isn't required, but it will keep Guest Additions working after kernel updates. Otherwise you'd have to reinstall them.
1. Insert the virtual CD using appropriate menu item in VirtualBox menu:

   *Please note that this is a host menu.* It's not inside the Debian VM. In fullscreen you may have to move your mouse to the top of the screen to reveal it. If it's hidden in windowed mode, see [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1176589/194694).

   [image: Menu screenshot]
2. Mount the CD:

   ```
    # mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
   ```
3. `cd` into the mounted directory:

   ```
    # cd /media/cdrom
   ```
4. Run the installer:

   ```
    # ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```

Or alternatively, if you really want to install from repository:

```
# apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: Where do I get the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso CD file from? The manual (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) says: "The VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux are provided on the same virtual CD-ROM file as the Guest Additions for Windows described above." but I only have a VirtualBox-4.3.30-101610-OSX.dmg file (MAC).

Comment: It's bundled with VirtualBox, just click the menu item I have highlighted on a screenshot and VBox will insert it.

Comment: Thanks! `sudo apt-cache pkgnames | grep virtualbox' doesn't give results. VBoxLinuxAdditions.run complains: tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
./install.sh: 357: ./install.sh: bzip2: not found. After installing bzip2 (apt-get install bzip2) I get the warning; "You appear to have a version of the VBoxGuestAdditions software
on your system which was installed from a different source or using a
different type of installer (...)". I am ignoring this.

Comment: It seems I have to install make and gcc, too. After installing them (apt-get install make, apt-get install gcc) I still get two warnings but some messages that indicate success, too.

Comment: Try installing the `build-essential` package.

Comment: Is there a possibilty to check if the installation was succesful?

Comment: If it works after a reboot, then yes, it was successful ;) Installer should finish without any errors. It may complain that you don't have X Window installed, but other than that, no errors should appear.

Comment: OK. That just broke my machine. It doesn't startup anymore. Sorry, doesn't convince me. As I failed doing it with the virtualbox manual, too. I'll give up for now.

Comment: It seems Debian comes with the Virtual Box Guest Additions pre-installed: http://www.binarytides.com/virtualbox-guest-additions-debian-wheezy/

Comment: @Gustave - you need to add "contrib" which are the non-free packages to your /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: There is no need for `sudo` when searching packages, e.g. with `apt-cache pkgnames`.

Comment: run upgrade first. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` -- kernel header may not find a match using `uname -r` otherwise. (Kali/Debian did this to me.). had to use `sh` to start the CD file, too. All the rest worked 100%. Solid answer, still.

Comment: I also had to install `x11-xserver-utils`.

Comment: ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run permission denied. Im in root.

Comment: @Slowaways Maybe the disc is mounted with `noexec` option? Try to remount with `exec`.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (Jessie) 64-bit):

1. Login as root with terminal command `su` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then type your root password
2. Update your APT database with `apt-get update`
3. Install the latest security updates with `apt-get upgrade`
4. Install required packages with `apt-get install build-essential
   module-assistant`
5. Configure your system for building kernel modules by running `m-a
   prepare`
6. Click on *Install Guest Additions…* from the VirtualBox *Devices* menu
7. Run `mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom`
8. Run `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, and follow the
   instructions on screen.

Comment: if you get an error that the mount point doesn't exist,  create it: mkdir /media/cdrom

Comment: The one that worked for me was:
$su
$apt-get update
$apt-get upgrade
$apt-get install build-essential module-assistant linux-header-$(uname -r)

Click mount Guest Additions on virtualbox

$sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Comment: I don't see any option that says "Install Guest Addition"  on the Devices menu there is only "Insert guest addition CD image"

Comment: @samayo its just changed menu item name in new version of VirtualBox from "Install Guest Additions" to "Insert guest addition CD image"
(http://imgur.com/a/9AVVC)

Answer (score 6):

I got permissions denied when I tried to run "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" so I changed the file `/etc/fstab` to `user,exec`. Other than that the steps that [gronostaj](https://superuser.com/a/950443/393570) mentioned worked perfectly.

[Explanation from virtualbox forum:](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=58799)

> ..the filesystem is mounted with the noexec option, so the execute
>   permission bits on all files are ignored, and you cannot directly
>   execute any program residing on this filesystem. Note that the noexec
>   mount option is implied by the user option in /etc/fstab. ... If you
>   use user and want to have executable files, use user,exec.

Comment: instead, just type `bash VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to save yourself the trouble.