# I hid the menu bar in VirtualBox, how to show it again?

Tags: virtualbox, app-menu

In top menu bar, I accidentally selected to hide that top menu bar ("File", "Help", etc).

As the bar has disappeared, I now cannot access the option to show it again. Not very thought through in my opinion.

[image: image description]

How do I show it again? My version is 5.0.4r.

Comment: Which VirtualBox window are you referring to? Which software version are you running?

Comment: Try RightCtrl + C

Comment: @jcbermu That hides even the bottom menu.

Comment: @jcbermu you save my day

Comment: @jcbermu that will go into Scaled Mode which will generally look worse... Also this will not show the menu again if you had previously explicitly hidden it.

Comment: @Redoman, RightCtrl + Home will provide you with the context menu to re-enable the menu bar.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Open virtual machine's settings, then *User Interface* page. Check this box:

[image: Screenshot of VM settings window on User Interface page, with an arrow pointing to a checkbox on the top toolbar]

Comment: As a side note, if the manager is not open, then the settings can be accessed by the shortcut Host+S, where Host is by default the right control key.

Comment: This was not useful for me. I ended up pressing right ctrl + all the letters starting from left to right on the keyboard until I figured out one that changed the display mode. VirtualBox is such a piece of crap.

Comment: @theMayer would you be so kind to say which which key?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work (anymore) on macOS.

Comment: I have this box checked on Ubuntu and I still can't see the menu bar. I also can't see the bottom bar, and that is also checked.

Comment: @AaronFranke Is the VM in fullscreen mode? You can quit it with Host+F (Host key is right Ctrl by default).

Comment: I figured it out, if I press Host+C then it shows the menu bars again.

Comment: Thanks! I had to do this and also shutdown/restart my VM for it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 117):

You can access the menu while the VM is running by <kbd>Right Control</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (by default). It will pop up as a contextual menu through which you will be able to reactivate the display of the menu.

Comment: This method is definitely the quickest.

Comment: for me by default it is not RightCtrl, but RightAlt+Home. Actually in status line it is shown at the very right. Also the modifier key can be set in VirtualBox Preferences / Input / Virtual Machine / Host Key Combination

Comment: This worked for me, none of the other methods have.

Comment: Thank you, I don't need to waste my screen with menu bar anymore.

Comment: What is the equivalent for MacOS?

Comment: Good answer. Also works in Dec 2022 with 6.1.40 (on Windows).

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem where the menus & status bar were gone.

The <kbd>Host + C</kbd> fixed the issue. Why?

Looking at the list of hotkeys (From the menu: *Input » Keyboard... » Keyboard Settings...*), the <kbd>Host + C</kbd> is assigned to the **Scaled Mode** function. The feature that let you change the size of your guest window to whatever dimensions you'd like (it does not even have to be a standard 4:3 or 16:9). This is great, but the side effect is that the VirtualBox system removes the menu & status bar because these may not fit properly when you resize your window in that mode.

So hitting <kbd>Host + C</kbd> again *fixes* the issue because it gets you out of the **Scaled Mode**. Now they can be sure that the menu & status bar will fit your window as expected.

[image]

---

**Note**: by default the <kbd>Host</kbd> key is the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key. That means if you have the habit of using that <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> in your day to day usage (like editing a file), you could end up triggering a VirtualBox guest feature without knowing it... some of which could be a shutdown or reboot of the guest!

Answer (score 3):

Temporary *removing* of %USERPROFILE%/.VirtualBox folder with

> mv %USERPROFILE%/.VirtualBox %USERPROFILE%/.VirtualBox_old

and *starting* a virtualbox from scratch
*allowed* to solve the issue with the help of

**hotkeys(Host+C & Host+Home, where Host=Right Ctrl)**

from this [tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPj4.png)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: open the Vbox preferences for VMs

[image]

Step 2: find the host key. In the example below, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[image]

Step 3: find the scale shortcut. In the example below, it is Host + <kbd>C</kbd>. Which means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]

As a result, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will show the menu, if it had disappeared due to the scale mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just move the .VDI file out of the folder made by VirtualBox (otherwise you will delete it by mistake)
2. Go to the VirtualBox manager program and delete the profile made for the virtual operating system by right click on its icon and selecting delete all
3. Try to recreate the virtual box but this time use existing .vdi file and the rest just same.

Comment: Why would I do this instead of re-enabling the toolbar in settings?

Comment: Good last resort if you searched the internet and didn't find an easier solution!

Comment: none of the Host+ worked for me , I had to do this