# Unable to install linux-guest-additions in debian

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

Iam using a debian and i have mounted the cdrom to install the guest additions in linux and it gave me the error as below.

```
root@Debian:/media/cdrom# sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
sudo: unable to execute ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run: Permission denied
```

So i have tried an alternative method from this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/503176/how-can-i-install-virtual-box-guest-addition?noredirect=1&lq=1) and i have tried the first command and it gave another error

```
root@Debian:/media/cdrom# apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
```

How to rectify this error and is there any other ways to install guest additions?

### System specifications:

```
OS -- Debian 8
VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 0):

The debian package is called *virtualbox-guest-utils*, so you need to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

My guess why the cdrom is not working, is that you mounted the cd as *noexec*. So either mount it as *exec* or copy the file to your home directory and execute it there. (Maybe you have to set it as executable before)